# Generate Excel Graph using Variables for Cell definition

Tags: excel, graph, vbscript, cells

I've been trying to generate, from a single Worksheet, several Graphs using a macro.
To do it I've registered the "creation of a graph" and then I've changed the "fixed cells" (eg. $B$55) with the command `Cells(2, R)` where `R` is a counter to move from a column to the next (steps of 3).
The macro gets blocked always at the same point (marked as **):

```
Sub Graph()
'
' Graph Macro
'

'
Dim R As Long

For R = 2 To 179

ActiveSheet.Cells(22, R).Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-102
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\254088\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Total_Lim.crtx")
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$B$3"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$4"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "={0,120}"
**ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!Cells(4,R),'StatAnalysis'!Cells(4,R)"**
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$5"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "={0,120}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!cells(5,R),'StatAnalysis'!cells(5,R)"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$6"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "={0,120}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!cells(6,R),'StatAnalysis'!cells(6,R)"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$12"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).XValues = "={0,120}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!cells(12,R),'StatAnalysis'!cells(12,R)"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$13"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).XValues = "={0,120}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!cells(13,R),'StatAnalysis'!cells(13,R)"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$16"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).XValues = "={0,120}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!cells(16,R),'StatAnalysis'!cells(16,R)"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).Name = "='StatAnalysis'!$A$17"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).XValues = "={0,120}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).Values = _
    "='StatAnalysis'!cells(17,R),'StatAnalysis'!cells(17,R)"
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

R = R + 3
Next

End Sub
```

It gives me back "Application-Defined or Object-defined Error"

does anybody have  a clue about it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set the Values of a Series you should supply either an Array of constant values or an Excel Range. First, I don't think you can plot a single Y-value against a pair of X-values, so you need to create a copy of the values in the cells you reference by Cells(#, R), say to Cells(#+1), so that each series has 2 points to match {0, 120}. Then, modify your code to this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Array(0, 120)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(#,R), ActiveSheet.Cells(#+1,R))
```

Hope that helps